# Is there a way to pass two arguments to a JavaScript function through HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an .html page that will allow for two string inputs (arguments) to be passed to the parameters of a .js function that will then return the longer of the 2 input values by comparing the string lengths.

First I wrote a .js that actually works while running it through VS CODE.  Here it is:

```
function twoStrings(stringA, stringB) {
    let longerStr;
    if (stringA.length > stringB.length) {
        return longerStr = stringA;
    } else return longerStr = stringB;
}
console.log(twoStrings("three", "Baseball"))
```

Then I tried to create an .html file that will create the user interface. But I think there is an issue that at the end of each input line it is calling the function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <title>Return Longest String.html</title>

</head>

<body>

    <p>Please input two words:</p>

    <input type="string" id="myInput1" oninput="twoStrings()">
    <input type="string" id="myInput2" oninput="twoStrings()">

    <p id="longerStr"> is the longer word</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="twoStringsV1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my .js

```
// 3. Write a function that takes in two strings and returns the longer of the two

function twoStrings(fval, sval) {
    var fval = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;
    var sval = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
    let longerStr;
    if (fval.length > sval.length) {
        return longerStr = fval;
    } else return longerStr = sval;
}
document.getElementById("longerStr").innerHTML = longerStr;
```

One other thing is that at the end of my .html, where I am asking the .js to produce an innerHTML I am getting this line:

[object HTMLParagraphElement]

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: If the function is assigning the variables itself, they don't need to be parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `return` statements, and put the assignment to `innerHTML` inside the function.

The function doesn't need any parameters, it gets the values of the two inputs itself.

```js
function twoStrings() {
  var fval = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;
  var sval = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
  let longerStr;
  if (fval.length > sval.length) {
    longerStr = fval;
  } else {
    longerStr = sval;
  }
  document.getElementById("longerStr").innerHTML = longerStr;
}
```

```html
<p>Please input two words:</p>

<input type="string" id="myInput1" oninput="twoStrings()">
<input type="string" id="myInput2" oninput="twoStrings()">

<p id="longerStr"> is the longer word</p>
```

The reason you were getting `[object HTMLParagraphElement]` is because outside the function, the global variable `longerStr` refers to the element `<p id="longerStr">`; converting an object to a string produces a result like that.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. I also realized I needed to append my innerHTML line to:

```document.getElementById("longerStr").innerHTML = longerStr + " is the longer word.";``` to get the string "is the longer word" to print. I know minor but important.

Answer (score 0):

There are some opportunities to use some more native elements:

- `<input type="string"` is not valid. type="text" is a valid type but is also the default and can be omitted.
- `<output>` would be a good fit for the computed result of a form calculation
- It would be simpler to handle the input event at a higher level (the overall form) rather than twice for each input and have the function bound to explicit inputs internally.
- You can also rely on the fact that elements specified with `id=x` are globally available on window as `x` to simply your inline handlers.

```js
function longerStr(stringA, stringB) {
  return stringA.length > stringB.length
    ? stringA
    : stringB;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Return Longest String.html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Please input two words:</p>

    <form oninput="longerStrOut.value=longerStr(myInput1.value, myInput2.value)">
      <input id="myInput1">
      <input id="myInput2">
      <p>
        <output name="longerStrOut"></output>
        is the longer word
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```